# (PHP) Sudden DOMDocument non-object problems

Tags: php, xml, parsing, domdocument

I've been developing a XML based PHP application which has suddenly "lost" all XML capabilities.

It just gives non-object errors on all DOMDocument/XML functions such as item, replaceChild, removeChild etc. generate non-object errors. Didn't happen yesterday and I haven't changed anything in code.

There's also errors like Failed to parse QName, error parsing attribute name in Entity etc. while XML data is still the same as for the last few months so no changes there.

Seems like DOMDocument "library" is completely unavailable while PHPinfo states that all required modules etc are enabled.

EDIT:

Now it seems like SimpleXML function asXML() is adding a new element to the document:

```
<ns:@attributes/>
```

Comment: If what you say is true then nothing can be wrong. So you are mistaken in some fashion - something has definitely changed. To figure out what is wrong we would need a sample of your code and the XML data along with details as to where you are encountering the errors. There isnt much we can do witht he little info you provided except make random guesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply.

In the end it was far from the actual XML or XML code.

I had a != comparator instead of !== which made it act like this. So next time I compare some variable to false value I'll probably remember that I should use !==.

Small things make big difference.